# The specified XML file does not have any associated style sheet

Tags: maven, jsf, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I am trying to fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162117/simplecrud-rejects-user-password and guys from TomEE mailing list asked me to reproduce the bug using Maven.
So I followed [Apache guide](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-mp-getting-started.html)

I created a new directory, then I entered command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.openejb.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=tomee-webapp-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.1
```

then

```
cd tomee-demo
```

then

```
mvn package tomee:run
```

then I putted [war file](https://www.wuala.com/Caterpillar/Documenti/canc/LAI_Login_war/?key=mywQ4L1p87kM)
in

```
maven/tomee-demo/target/apache-tomee/webapps/
```

And tried to load webpage

```
http://localhost:8080/LAI_pezzi_Login/Login.xhtml
```

But I obtain the message

```
The specified XML file does not have any associated style sheet. Document tree is shown below

<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<h:form styleClass="loginPanelStyle">
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="false"/>
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
<f:facet name="header"> Login Panel </f:facet>
<h:outputText value="Username : "/>
<p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginController.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Username!" message="fc">
<f:validateLength minimum="1"/>
</p:inputText>
<h:outputText value="Password : "/>
<p:password id="password" value="#{loginController.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter password!">
<f:validateLength minimum="1"/>
</p:password>
<f:facet name="footer">
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" actionListener="#{loginController.login}" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0"/>
</f:facet>
</p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I also tried to deploy the WAR file on a Tomcat downloaded from Apache website, and the WAR file works correctly

Comment: You don't have JSF (more specifically the faces servlet) loaded and/or mapped.

Comment: Should not WAR file be "plug and play"? I mean, the WAR is coming from a well working project in Eclipse. When I start TomEE in Eclipse the webpage loads correctly. What have I to do?

Comment: Have a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxj.html), does adding the servlet mapping (you probably want the extension mapping for your demo) as shown there solve your problem?

Comment: Do you mean web.xml file? I don't know what extension mapping is

Comment: Yes, this is what the tutorial I linked is about. It's basically adding a `<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>`.

Comment: Which web.xml should I edit, `/maven/tomee-demo/target/apache-tomee/webapps/LAI_pezzi_Login/WEB-INF/web.xml` or `/maven/tomee-demo/target/apache-tomee/conf/web.xml` ?

Comment: I don't know, try editing both?

Comment: No positive effects, and those files are being regenerated every time, so changes are lost

Comment: I tried on a Tomcat downloaded from Apache website, and the WAR file works correctly

Comment: Ooook. I really don't know why, but now TomEE works with URL `http://localhost:8080/LAI_pezzi_Login/faces/Login.xhtml` so it was true that I was using a wrong URL. During the past days I also tried that URL but it did not work before... If you fill an answer with things you already wrote, I can give you the green mark. I am sorry for BalusC too because he was right too, but I don't know why the web page did not work at that moment I tried his suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need to tell JSF which URLs it should process by specifying a servlet-mapping in your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml<‌​/url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your experience with left-over configuration files reminds me why I touch maven with a 10' pole only.